# как исключить некоторые маршруты Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\SpaController::class, 'index'])
->where('any', '.*')
->middleware('auth');


нужно чтобы не срабатывало условие выше если маршрут будет один из этих:
password/reset
login
logout
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто укажите нужные роуты выше данного правила.Оно должно быть всегда самым нижним.

т.е. должно получиться что-то вроде

```
   Route::get('/password/reset',[AuthController::class,'reset']);
   Route::get('/login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
   Route::get('/logout',[AuthController::class,'logout']);
   Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\SpaController::class, 'index'])
->where('any', '.*')
->middleware('auth');
```

В этом случае ваши роуты будут работать